# How can I update a database string value from a TextBox?

Tags: asp.net

I cant update my database through textbox.in the case of numeric value i can update but cant with a string value.
my coding is...

```
SqlCommand cmdup= new SqlCommand("UPDATE [port1] SET [prt1]=@prt1 WHERE [no]= 1",cn);
cmdup.Parameters.Add("@prt1", TextBox1.Text);  
cmdup.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

if any one know the ans: reply me

Comment: And what error do you receive?

Comment: I will never understand why people like to roll their questions back to poorly written sentences...

Comment: Not everyone knows or has a full grasp of the English language

Comment: Ahh I understand what you were saying, you edited the question to make it easier to understand, and then they rolled it back.  Got it, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend explicitly defining the parameter type to match the type in the DB, and passing the value to Parameters.Add as the appropriate type.

e.g. at the moment, you are passing a string typed value to Parameters.Add, and not defining the type explicitly. Therefore, it will assume the data type from the type of value supplied...so the @prt1 type will be passed in to the DB as NVARCHAR I believe.

If the prt1 field is an INTEGER for example, much safer IMHO to do something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prt", SqlDbType.Int,4).Value = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prt", Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text));
```

I always like to fully define the type of the parameters I pass in to SQL to rule out any potential, unexpected issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check the datatype for the @prt1 to see if it is a Int value because you are setting to the same column two different values.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the textBox to Integer as you want to insert a numeric value i.e. Int64.Parse("Textbox1.Text");   well with string it does have problems.

Comment: or with Int32 or int.Parse("txt1.Text");  but 64 is much preferabble. . . 32 or 64 are bits, as c sharp strongly typed language so it has strict specification every  datatypes

Comment: you can edit your answer, rather than putting it in bits in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: Does `prt` maybe only accept numeric values?